# Java: Jackson serializing is creating 2 nodes

Tags: serialization, jackson, xml-serialization

On the client side of a REST query, my Java client, using Jackson (om.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.0) makes the following call:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
ByteArrayOutputStream streamTemplate = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
xmlMapper.writeValue(streamTemplate, template);
streamTemplate.flush();
```

The class it is serializing has:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Datasources")
private List<DataSource> datasources;
```

And Datasource has several properties, none named Datasources.

But the XML created has:

SqlServer
        SQL
        System.Data.SqlClient
        Data Source=mssql.windward.net;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=demo;Password=demo

Why the two Datasources nodes? On the server side which is a C# ASP.NET WebApi2 app, it is not deserializing the Datasource part, and I assume that's due to the embedded Datasources node.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps the list has more than one element for some reason? Or maybe the serialized representation for `DataSource` is unexpected, and perhaps a connection `String` might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trns out the answer is simple. Annotate as follows:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Datasources")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Datasource")
private List<DataSource> datasources;
```